# Is there any possibility to add audio/video chat facility in android using GTalk/Skype

Tags: android

I want to add Audio/Video chat facility inside my application. Can anyone help me out for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can launch intent. Which will start GTalk or Skype..

```
Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("write the package name for GTalk / Skype");
startActivity( LaunchIntent );
```

these links can be helpful :-

[one similar link](https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=groups2&passive=1209600&continue=http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/363a5fb2d2533146&followup=http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/363a5fb2d2533146&authuser=0)

[a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872063/android-launch-an-application-from-another-application) and To know the package name see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789462/find-package-name-for-android-apps-to-use-intent-to-launch-market-app-from-web) link