# Read the package name of an Android APK

Tags: android, apk

I need to get the *package name* of an Android APK. I have tried to unzip the APK and read the contents of the `AndroidManifest.xml` file but it seems that it's not a text file.

How can I extract the APK's package name?

Comment: https://www.sisik.eu/apk-tool

Answer (score 385, accepted):

```
aapt dump badging <path-to-apk> | grep package:\ name
```

Comment: Is there a way to call this from within Android code?  I want to be able to launch a package of an apk I download through my app.

Comment: appt dump badging <path-to-apk> | grep package:\ name

Comment: @Campiador you can just type up until the pipe `|`, press enter and then just search the output for your desired parameter. Just remember that `aapt` needs to be in your path

Comment: See my answer below if you need to get this programmatically (for a script).

Comment: @Campiador: for Windows, uses findstr command instead of grep

Comment: Upvoted despite that it extracts the whole line instead of the package name only, which unfortunately is not suitable for my script. But it put me on the right path.

Comment: @hackbod I have posted a question and would like a comment from someone from google, hope you can spare some time to reply http://stackoverflow.com/q/36614857/1503130 thanks.

Comment: `aapt` command is located under `Android\SDK\build-tools\version`. on windows command can be `aapt dump badging <path-to-apk> | findstr -i "package: name"` or `aapt dump badging <path-to-apk>`

Comment: apkanalyzer can be found under Android/sdk/tools/bin folder. Use `apkanalyzer manifest application-id <APKFILE>` to print package name of apk.

Comment: `aapt` on macOS located in `~/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/{version}`

Comment: On Arch, download `android-sdk-build-tools` from the AUR

Comment: On mac, if you still see `command not found: aapt`, try with './' i.e 

```cd ~/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/{version}``` and then 
```./aapt dump badging <path-to-apk> | grep package:\ name```

Answer (score 87):

Install the apk on your Android device. Then

> you can launch `adb shell` and execute `pm list packages -f`, which shows the package name for each installed apk.

This is taken from
[Find package name for Android apps to use Intent to launch Market app from web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789462/find-package-name-for-android-apps-to-use-intent-to-launch-market-app-from-web).

Comment: Also, you will have to ensure that you are running with elevated privileges. Basically, in the terminal, use the `su` command first.

Comment: to search for specific package name `pm list packages -f | grep term-to-search-for`

Answer (score 24):

Based on @hackbod answer ... but related to Windows.

`aapt` command is located on `Android\Sdk\build-tools\<build-tools-version>`.
If you need more info about what is `aapt` command (Android Asset Packaging Tool) read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/28234956/812915

The `dump` sub-command of `aapt` is used to display the values of individual elements or parts of a package: `aapt dump badging <path-to-apk>`

To view only the line(s) containing the occurrence of `package: name`, use `findstr` (in Windows PowerShell or CMD):

`aapt dump badging <path-to-apk> | findstr -n /C:"package: name"`

Remember to surround <path-to-apk> with quotes if it contains spaces.

Hope it help other windows user!

Answer (score 16):

If you are looking at google play and want to know its package name then you can look at url or address bar. You will get package name. Here `com.landshark.yaum` is the package name

```
 https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.landshark.yaum&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS5sYW5kc2hhcmsueWF1bSJd
```

Answer (score 13):

If you open the AndroidManifest.xml using MS Notepad, search for phrase `package` and you'll find following:

```
package manifest $xxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx |
```

where xxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx is your package name, just written with a space after each character.

It's useful way when you don't have any specific tools installed.

Comment: This is especially useful if the code for the app is on github! Much easier than the other methods, thanks!

Comment: I unpacked the APK, but AndroidManifest.xml was a binary file. Weird but true.

Answer (score 13):

The following bash script will display the package name and the main activity name:

**apk_package.sh**

```
package=$(aapt dump badging "$*" | awk '/package/{gsub("name=|'"'"'","");  print $2}')
activity=$(aapt dump badging "$*" | awk '/activity/{gsub("name=|'"'"'","");  print $2}')
echo
echo "   file : $1"
echo "package : $package"
echo "activity: $activity"
```

run it like so:

```
apk_package.sh /path/to/my.apk
```

Comment: Never combine grep and sed with awk. Using awk is enough.

Answer (score 12):

Since its mentioned in Android documentation that **AAPT has been deprecated**, getting the package name using AAPT2 command in Linux is as follows:

`./aapt2 dump packagename <path_to_apk>`

Since I am using an older version of Gradle build, I had to download a newer version of AAPT2 as mentioned here :

[Download AAPT2 from Google Maven](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/aapt2#download_aapt2)

Using the build-tools in my sdk - 25.0.3, 26.0.1 and 27.0.3, executing the aapt2 command shows an error: Unable to open 'packagename': No such file or directory. That's why I went for the newer versions of AAPT2.

I used 3.3.0-5013011 for linux.

Comment: For aapt2 version 2.19, I had to do `aapt2 dump /path/to/apk | grep "Package name"`

Answer (score 8):

## A Programmatic Answer

If you need to do this programmatically, it's a little more involved than just getting the answer into your brain. I have a script that I use to sign all of our apps, but each use a different key. Here are 2 ways to get **just the Package Name** as output so you can put it in a variable or do whatever you need with it.

Example output: `com.example.appname` (and nothing more)

#### Requirements

`aapt` - Android Asset Packaging Tool, part of the [SDK Tools download](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Other)

#### Solution 1

Using `awk` specify `'` as the Field Separator, search for a line with `package: name=`, and print only the 2nd "field" in the line:

```
aapt dump badging /path/to/file.apk | awk -v FS="'" '/package: name=/{print $2}'
```

A weakness of this method is that it relies on aapt to output the package information fields in the same order:

```
package: name='com.example.appname' versionCode='3461' versionName='2.2.4' platformBuildVersionName='4.2.2-1425461'
```

We have no commitments from the developers to maintain this format.

#### Solution 2

Using `awk` specify `"` as the Field Separator, search for a line with `package=`, and print only the 2nd "field" in the line:

```
aapt list -a /path/to/file.apk | awk -v FS='"' '/package=/{print $2}'
```

A weakness of this method is that it relies on aapt to output `package=` only in the `Android Manifest:` section of the output. We have no commitments from the developers to maintain this format.

#### Solution 3

Expand the apk file with `apktool d` and read the AndroidManifest.xml.

This would be the best method, but the AndroidManifest.xml is a binary file and all the SO answers I see for converting it to text do not work. (Using `apktool d` instead of a simple `unzip` is supposed to do this for you, but it does not.) **Please comment if you have an solution to this issue**

Comment: Thanks for giving more information to understand rather than just giving a single line of command to copy.

Answer (score 7):

A simple solution would be Open Android Studio -> Build -> Analyze Apk... browse and select the APK now you can find the package name and pretty much you can read.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `Analyze APK...` from the Build menu in Android Studio, it will display the package name at the top of new window.

Answer (score 4):

On Mac:

**Way 1:**

```
zgong$ /Users/zgong/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/29.0.3/aapt dump badging ~/Downloads/NonSIMCC-151-app-release-signed.apk
package: name='com.A.B' versionCode='2020111801' versionName='1.0.40' compileSdkVersion='29' compileSdkVersionCodename='10'
sdkVersion:'24'
targetSdkVersion:'29'
......
```

**Way 2:**

```
/Users/zgong/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/29.0.3/aapt2 dump packagename ~/Downloads/NonSIMCC-151-app-release-signed.apk
com.A.B
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the best and simplest way to extract **only** the package name in Linux is

```
aapt dump badging <APK_path> | grep package | sed -r "s/package: name='([a-z0-9.]*)'.*/\1/"
```

Explanation:

1. AAPT extracts the APK information
2. Grep "package" to keep only the line about the package information
3. Make sed replace the whole line with the package name only using the following regex: `package: name='([a-z0-9.]*)'.*` and replacing with the first (and only) matching group.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have the Android SDK installed, like in some test scenarios, you can get the package name using the following bash method:

```sh
getAppIdFromApk() {
  local apk_path="$1"

  # regular expression (required)
  local re="^\"L.*/MainActivity;"
  # sed substitute expression
  local se="s:^\"L\(.*\)/MainActivity;:\1:p"
  # tr expression
  local te=' / .';

  local app_id="$(unzip -p $apk_path classes.dex | strings | grep -Eo $re | sed -n -e $se | tr $te)"

  echo "$app_id"
}
```

Tested on a mac. 'strings' and 'unzip' are standard on most linux's, so should work on linux too.

Comment: This is the java package name of the Mainactivity class though, might not match the app's package name.

Answer (score 3):

A very simple method is to use apkanalyzer.

```
apkanalyzer manifest application-id "${_path_to_apk}"
```

Comment: Works for me, but replacing all "${_path_to_apk}" placeholder by apk path. Example: apkanalyzer manifest application-id /Users/user/..../project/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to know package name, run adb logcat, launch the activity you want , you will get a hint on the package name.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to use aapt list and use sed to parse through that:

`aapt list -a $PATH_TO_YOUR_APK | sed -n "/^Package Group[^s]/s/.*name=//p"`

Comment: Package Group Name is only coincidentally the same as Package Name in some apps. You really need to be using the `A:package="com.example.appname"` in the `Android Manifest:` section if you do `aapt list -a`

Answer (score 2):

There's a very simple way if you got your APK allready on your Smartphone. Just use one of these APPs:

[Package Name Viewer Apps](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=Package%20Name%20Viewer&c=apps&hl=de)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Android Studio for this. Select your APK via the GUI menu:
[image]

And open manifest as usual:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

To use this in batch scripting it's handy to have the script return just the package name (e.g. for uninstalling an app when you have the APK).

Here's the script I use:

```
# extract the android package id from a built apk file
# usage ./getPackageName.sh <path-to-apk>
line=`aapt dump badging "$1" | grep package:\ name`

# above returns:
# package: name='com.calvium.myapp' versionCode='1' versionName='1.0'
if [[ $line =~ name=\'(.+)\'\ versionCode ]]; then
    echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
else
    echo "Failed to find package name"
    exit 1
fi
```

[available on gist](https://gist.github.com/benvium/cedbbe53f4e7478e611f)

So you could write:

adb uninstall `./getPackageName.sh file.apk`

Answer (score 1):

You can extract AndroidManifest.xml from the APK, remove all NULL bytes, skip everything until after the string 'manifest', and then you are at a length byte followed by the package name (and what comes after it). For the difficult task I use the great [GEMA](http://gema.sourceforge.net/new/index.shtml) tool, so the command looks like this:

```
7z e -so MyApp.apk AndroidManifest.xml | gema '\x00=' | gema -match 'manifest<U1><U>=@substring{0;@char-int{$1};$2}'
```

Of course, you can use any other tool to do the filtering.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows following worked for me:

```
:: // Initializing variables
SET adb="C:\Users\<User name>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb"
SET aapt="C:\Users\<User name>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\22.0.0\aapt"
SET APKPath=C:\Users\<User name>\Desktop\APK\Instant_Instal\

CD %APKPath%

:: // Searching for apk file and storing it
FOR /F "delims=" %%f IN ('dir /S /B *.apk') DO SET "APKFullPath=%%f"
SET apk=%APKFullPath%

:: // Command adb install apk, run apk
%adb% install %apk%

:: // Fetching package name from apk
%aapt% dump badging %APKFullPath% | FIND "package: name=" > temp.txt
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims='" %%s IN (temp.txt) DO SET pkgName=%%s
del temp.txt

:: // Launching apk
%adb% shell monkey -p %pkgName% -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 1

pause
```

**Note**

Please edit the paths of adb, aapt, APKPath according to the paths of adb, aapt, and the apk location in your system.

**Working:**

- Here I have added the apk in a folder on Desktop "\Desktop\APK\Instant_Instal\".
- The command `%adb% install %apk%` installs the application if the device is connected.
- This `%aapt% dump badging %APKFullPath% | FIND "package: name=" > temp.txt` fetches package name and a few other details like version etc. of the apk and stores in a temp.txt file in same location as that of the apk.
- FOR /F "tokens=2 delims='" %%s IN (temp.txt) DO SET pkgName=%%s`extracts the package name and assigns to`pkgName` variable
- Finally `%adb% shell monkey -p %pkgName% -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 1` launches the app.

In essence the above code installs the apk from given location in desktop "Desktop\APK\Instant_Instal\" to the device and launches the application.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the package name programmatically by :

```
packageManager.getPackageArchiveInfo(apkFilePath, 0)?.packageName
```

Comment: other answers, use external tools but by this answer you can extract your package name in your android app.

Answer (score 0):

you can instal **Package_Name_Viewer.apk** on your emulator and next you can see package name of all instaled app on your emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I also tried the de-compilation thing, it works but recently I found the easiest  way:

1. Download and install Appium from [Appium website](http://appium.io/)
2. Open Appium->Android setting, choose the target apk file. And then you get everything you want, the package info, activity info.

Answer (score 0):

As I don't was able to find the package name in the .apk file with editor (like suggested above), I have checked the functions in the App "ES Datei Explorer" / "ES File Explorer" (free version) that I had installed already. 
In this tool, the package name is showed properly.
As I think a good file explorer should not be missing on a phone, I suggest to use this tool (if you already have installed the apk on an mobile and have to know the  package name).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read the package name of a typical APK file in your app, there's an easy way to analyze the [PackageInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo):

```
fun getAPKPackageName(apkFile: File?): String? {
        if (apkFile == null || !apkFile.isFile || !apkFile.exists()) return null
        val apkFilePath = apkFile.absolutePath
        if (apkFilePath.isNullOrEmpty()) return null
        val packageManager = App.context.packageManager ?: return null
        val packageInfo = packageManager.getPackageArchiveInfo(apkFilePath, 0) ?: return null
        return packageInfo.packageName
    }
```