# how to print a specified parameter when using aapt dump

Tags: android, cmd, substring, apk, aapt

I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6289168/1137788) that the command

```
aapt dump badging foo.apk
```

prints all the details of the specified package.

Is it possible to print any one property, say sdkversion?
Something like

```
aapt dump badging -sdkversion foo.apk
```

P.S I'm using command prompt in windows.

**EDIT**

I am trying to store the package name in a variable.
As of now, I have this code

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('aapt dump badging foo.apk') do (
     REM each line of the output
)
```

I am able to retrieve each line of the output. Now I have to extract the package name from the string. 
For instance the first line is

> package: name='com.timeplusq.noob' versionCode='15' versionName='1.5'

which is retrieved in the first iteration of the for loop. How do I extract the package name from it.  I thought string manipulation would be straight forward, it is not. 
**So how do I extract the package name from the string?**

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a Unix system or having cygwin on Windows, you could try this command :

```
aapt dump badging foo.apk | grep sdkVersion | sed -E "s/^[^:]+:\'(.*)\'$/\1/"
```

the **regexp** will extract the value of the line selected by **grep** command

**EDIT :**

In a Windows system, you can use the following script saved as a `.cmd` :

```
@echo off
set property=sdkVersion:'10'
set property=%property:sdkVersion=%
set property=%property:~2,-1%

echo.%property%
```

Comment: ah no! I'm just using command prompt in windows.. any solutions for that?

Comment: Er. I've never used batch scripts, so I'm a bit confused. I have updated the question. Can you please answer that? Thanks! :)

Comment: Well, I tried to write a full script but I don't know enough about DOS scripting to do that... What about a simple Java application to do the job ?

Comment: This is not helping on windows!