# AndroidManifest.xml processed output tool

Tags: android, android-manifest, adb, android-sdk-tools

I'm going off a very vague memory, but there's a tool that is included in the Android SDK which, when you run it against an unsigned or a debug-signed application APK (I do not recall which), it outputs a 'processed' AndroidManifest file.

Howevever, I forgotten what the tool/flags are and I cannot find it online! Can someone help me? I hope the terminology is understandable but, you ran this SDK tool with a parameter on your unsigned/debug-signed APK (as I say, I can't recall which) and it generated an output which (I think) is what the Google Play store reads.

Sorry it's incredibly vague; if I find the tool I mean, I'll update this thread with it

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/

Comment: apktool is not provided with sdk.. are you talking about jarsigner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you meant this:

```
    $ aapt dump badging <my_apk.apk>
```

Comment: How do u run this on a windows machine?

Comment: @AlexVPerl Would this answer help? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12426137/how-to-print-a-specified-parameter-when-using-aapt-dump)