# Android app issue

Tags: android

While running the Android app in emulator each time I am getting the following error.

> Installation failed with message null. It is possible that this issue
>   is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is
>   present, and then re-installing.
>
> WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!
>
> Do you want to uninstall the existing application?

I tried to un-install the existing app but could not find that in settings.

Can someone please throw us some light on this plz...

Comment: you can use adb command to uninstall an app from emulator `adb uninstall com.my.firstapp`. see this post for more [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25927124/how-to-uninstall-apk-or-execute-adb-command-automatically-before-run-or-debug)

Comment: This usually means DDMS timed out. Try setting longer timeout. If you are using ARM emulator, try using x86 emulators instead, it will be much faster.