# Expo stuck on "Config syncing" while ejecting to expokit

Tags: react-native, expo

While trying to eject a project from expokit, it won't finish and get's stuck at `config syncing` for over an hour.

[image]

This also happens when I create a new project with expo and then run `expo run:android`

Comment: got the same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved below step.

---

remove files for new feeling.

```
rm -rf android
rm -rf node_modules
rm yarn.lock
rm package-lock.json
```

---

update node. I used nvm.

---

```
npm uninstall -g sharp-cli

yarn install
```

---

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps your copy of sharp-cli is corrupted?

```bash
npm uninstall -g sharp-cli && npm install -g sharp-cli
```

If the problem persists you can just uninstall sharp-cli and it will skip this step.