# MI Max 2 Error: App not installed

Tags: react-native, apk, android-install-apk

I am a react-native app developer an owe mi max 2 and trying to install a apk into it but it is showing an error:

> "The package conflicts with an existing package by the same name"

.

Although i have uninstalled the previous version of it but still it is showing this error. It is also giving error. What should i do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must uninstall application via **adb** instead, although you already uninstalled application using the normal method

Run this command when you connect android phone with PC via USB `adb uninstall <package_name>`

more info read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25927723/1754750)