# app installation time not being detected correctly upon reinstallation from android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, installation

I am using below code to obtain the installation time of my app

```
    PackageManager p = this.getPackageManager();
    ApplicationInfo apinf = null;

    apinf = p.getApplicationInfo(this.getPackageName(), 0);
    String apkFile = apinf.sourceDir;
    installTime = new File(apkFile).lastModified();
```

If I reinstall apk after making some source code changes - via android studio - the `installTime` is not updated. If however, I manually uninstall app from my device. the new installTime is correctly shown next time.

How do I write code to detect installation time of apk file that is reinstalled by android studio?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in your code. You need to understand that when you re-run or stop/start the android application from android studio, it does not uninstall/re-install the application to phone. Rather it copies changed classes/resources to installation directory on phone. So the modified time of apk file is not updated.

You can try to uninstall the application first, and then re-run the application from android studio. Or if you don't want to get into trouble of uninstalling the application from phone every-time, you can configure your IDE to uninstall the application before re-running. It is described here: [Android Studio : How to uninstall APK (or execute adb command) automatically before Run or Debug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25927124/android-studio-how-to-uninstall-apk-or-execute-adb-command-automatically-bef)

Comment: `Rather it copies changed classes/resources to installation directory on phone` - how to detect this from java code?