# Build succeeds but nothing's Happening during the Deploy

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm having a bit of a weird situation.

I had to switch work machine's due to a loss of info, I just Went from Windows to Mac Visual Studio
I got my Repository and everything's seemed fine.

However When i'm Building the Application to my Android device, The build succeeds(I did see the log says Failed But the IDE is not mentioning anything I'm Confused) but It just stops and nothing happens after that.

I have a log I'll post.

The only real issue I can spot is I cant use the IOS side, as I need Xcode 11 and I cant go above 9(Higher OS will cause me to loose other Programs I need like Cs6)

```
Build started 2020/01/16 9:26:54 AM.
__________________________________________________
Project "/Users/iMac/Desktop/Roy/EcomVersioning-master/Ecombeta/Ecombeta.Android/Ecombeta.Android.csproj" (Install target(s)):

Build started 2020/01/16 9:26:54 AM.
__________________________________________________
Project "/Users/iMac/Desktop/Roy/EcomVersioning-master/Ecombeta/Ecombeta.Android/Ecombeta.Android.csproj" (Install target(s)):

Target _ResolveSdks:
    Found Java SDK version 1.8.0.
    Found Java SDK version 1.8.0.
Target _ResolveSdks:
    Found Java SDK version 1.8.0.
    Found Java SDK version 1.8.0.
Target _GetProjectReferenceTargetFrameworkProperties:
    __________________________________________________
    Project "/Users/iMac/Desktop/Roy/EcomVersioning-master/Ecombeta/Ecombeta.Android/Ecombeta.Android.csproj" is building "/Users/iMac/Desktop/Roy/EcomVersioning-master/Ecombeta/Ecombeta/Ecombeta.csproj" (GetTargetFrameworks target(s)):

Target ResolveProjectReferences:
    __________________________________________________
    Project "/Users/iMac/Desktop/Roy/EcomVersioning-master/Ecombeta/Ecombeta.Android/Ecombeta.Android.csproj" is building "/Users/iMac/Desktop/Roy/EcomVersioning-master/Ecombeta/Ecombeta/Ecombeta.csproj" (GetTargetPath target(s)):

Target _VerifyXamarinAndroidSupportVersions:
  Skipping target "_VerifyXamarinAndroidSupportVersions" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _GetProjectReferenceTargetFrameworkProperties:
    __________________________________________________
    Project "/Users/iMac/Desktop/Roy/EcomVersioning-master/Ecombeta/Ecombeta.Android/Ecombeta.Android.csproj" is building "/Users/iMac/Desktop/Roy/EcomVersioning-master/Ecombeta/Ecombeta/Ecombeta.csproj" (GetTargetFrameworks target(s)):

Target ResolveProjectReferences:
    __________________________________________________
    Project "/Users/iMac/Desktop/Roy/EcomVersioning-master/Ecombeta/Ecombeta.Android/Ecombeta.Android.csproj" is building "/Users/iMac/Desktop/Roy/EcomVersioning-master/Ecombeta/Ecombeta/Ecombeta.csproj" (GetTargetPath target(s)):

Target _VerifyXamarinAndroidSupportVersions:
  Skipping target "_VerifyXamarinAndroidSupportVersions" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _CheckInstantRunCondition:
    Dex Fast Deployment Enabled: False
Target _ResolveMonoAndroidSdks:
    MonoAndroid Tools: /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Android.framework/Libraries/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/
    Android Platform API level: 28
    TargetFrameworkVersion: v9.0
    Android NDK: 
    Android SDK: /Users/iMac/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/
    Android SDK Build Tools: /Users/iMac/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/28.0.3/
    Java SDK: /Users/iMac/Library/Developer/Xamarin/jdk/microsoft_dist_openjdk_1.8.0.25/
    Application Java class: android.app.Application
Target _ValidateAndroidPackageProperties:
      PackageName: com.lionmarketing.ecombeta
Target _ResolveLibraryProjectImports:
  Skipping target "_ResolveLibraryProjectImports" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _BuildLibraryImportsCache:
  Skipping target "_BuildLibraryImportsCache" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _BuildAdditionalResourcesCache:
  Skipping target "_BuildAdditionalResourcesCache" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _CreateAdditionalResourceCache:
  Skipping target "_CreateAdditionalResourceCache" because it has no outputs.
Target ProcessGoogleServicesJson:
  Skipping target "ProcessGoogleServicesJson" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _GenerateAndroidResourceDir:
  Skipping target "_GenerateAndroidResourceDir" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _GenerateLayoutBindings:
  Skipping target "_GenerateLayoutBindings" because it has no outputs.
Target _ConvertLibraryResourcesCases:
    Touching "obj/Debug/stamp/_ConvertLibraryResourcesCases.stamp".
Target _CheckInstantRunCondition:

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2680,3): warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols" that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed.
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2680,3): warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect" that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed.
Done building target "_ResolveSatellitePaths" in project "Ecombeta.Android.csproj".
Target _CopyConfigFiles:
  Skipping target "_CopyConfigFiles" because it has no inputs.
Target _ConvertPdbFiles:
  Skipping target "_ConvertPdbFiles" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _LinkAssembliesNoShrink:
  Skipping target "_LinkAssembliesNoShrink" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _CopyConfigFiles:
  Skipping target "_CopyConfigFiles" because it has no inputs.
Target _GenerateJavaStubs:
  Skipping target "_GenerateJavaStubs" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _ConvertCustomView:
  Skipping target "_ConvertCustomView" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _AddStaticResources:
  Skipping target "_AddStaticResources" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _GeneratePackageManagerJava:
  Skipping target "_GeneratePackageManagerJava" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _ResolveSatellitePaths:
    No way to resolve conflict between "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" and "mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e". Choosing "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" arbitrarily.
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2680,3): warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols" that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed.
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2680,3): warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect" that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed.
Done building target "_ResolveSatellitePaths" in project "Ecombeta.Android.csproj".
Target _CopyConfigFiles:
  Skipping target "_CopyConfigFiles" because it has no inputs.
Target _ConvertPdbFiles:
  Skipping target "_ConvertPdbFiles" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _LinkAssembliesNoShrink:
  Skipping target "_LinkAssembliesNoShrink" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _CopyConfigFiles:
  Skipping target "_CopyConfigFiles" because it has no inputs.
Target _GenerateJavaStubs:
  Skipping target "_GenerateJavaStubs" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _ConvertCustomView:
  Skipping target "_ConvertCustomView" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _AddStaticResources:
  Skipping target "_AddStaticResources" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _GeneratePackageManagerJava:
  Skipping target "_GeneratePackageManagerJava" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _CreateAdditionalResourceCache:
  Skipping target "_CreateAdditionalResourceCache" because it has no outputs.
Target _GenerateAndroidAssetsDir:
  Skipping target "_GenerateAndroidAssetsDir" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _PrepareCreateBaseApk:
  Skipping target "_PrepareCreateBaseApk" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _CreateBaseApk:
  Skipping target "_CreateBaseApk" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _CreateAdditionalResourceCache:
  Skipping target "_CreateAdditionalResourceCache" because it has no outputs.
Target _CompileJava:
  Skipping target "_CompileJava" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _CompileNativeAssemblySources:
  Skipping target "_CompileNativeAssemblySources" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _CreateApplicationSharedLibraries:
  Skipping target "_CreateApplicationSharedLibraries" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _CreateAdditionalResourceCache:
  Skipping target "_CreateAdditionalResourceCache" because it has no outputs.
Target _CompileToDalvikWithDx:
  Skipping target "_CompileToDalvikWithDx" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _CreateAdditionalResourceCache:
  Skipping target "_CreateAdditionalResourceCache" because it has no outputs.
Target _GenerateAndroidAssetsDir:
  Skipping target "_GenerateAndroidAssetsDir" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _PrepareCreateBaseApk:
  Skipping target "_PrepareCreateBaseApk" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _CreateBaseApk:
  Skipping target "_CreateBaseApk" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _CreateAdditionalResourceCache:
  Skipping target "_CreateAdditionalResourceCache" because it has no outputs.
Target _CompileJava:
  Skipping target "_CompileJava" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _CompileNativeAssemblySources:
  Skipping target "_CompileNativeAssemblySources" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _CreateApplicationSharedLibraries:
  Skipping target "_CreateApplicationSharedLibraries" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _CreateAdditionalResourceCache:
  Skipping target "_CreateAdditionalResourceCache" because it has no outputs.
Target _CompileToDalvikWithDx:
  Skipping target "_CompileToDalvikWithDx" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target _CopyPackage:
    Copying file from "/Users/iMac/Desktop/Roy/EcomVersioning-master/Ecombeta/Ecombeta.Android/obj/Debug/android/bin/com.lionmarketing.ecombeta.apk" to "/Users/iMac/Desktop/Roy/EcomVersioning-master/Ecombeta/Ecombeta.Android/bin/Debug/com.lionmarketing.ecombeta.apk".
Target _CopyPackage:
    Copying file from "/Users/iMac/Desktop/Roy/EcomVersioning-master/Ecombeta/Ecombeta.Android/obj/Debug/android/bin/com.lionmarketing.ecombeta.apk" to "/Users/iMac/Desktop/Roy/EcomVersioning-master/Ecombeta/Ecombeta.Android/bin/Debug/com.lionmarketing.ecombeta.apk".
Target _ResolveAndroidSigningKey:
    Creating "obj/Debug/android_debug_keystore.flag" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
Target _Sign:
    /Users/iMac/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/28.0.3/zipalign -p 4 "/Users/iMac/Desktop/Roy/EcomVersioning-master/Ecombeta/Ecombeta.Android/obj/Debug/android/bin/com.lionmarketing.ecombeta.apk" "bin/Debug//com.lionmarketing.ecombeta-Signed.apk" 
Target _ResolveAndroidSigningKey:
    Creating "obj/Debug/android_debug_keystore.flag" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
Target _Sign:
    /Users/iMac/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/28.0.3/zipalign -p 4 "/Users/iMac/Desktop/Roy/EcomVersioning-master/Ecombeta/Ecombeta.Android/obj/Debug/android/bin/com.lionmarketing.ecombeta.apk" "bin/Debug//com.lionmarketing.ecombeta-Signed.apk" 
    /Users/iMac/Library/Developer/Xamarin/jdk/microsoft_dist_openjdk_1.8.0.25/bin/java -jar /Users/iMac/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/28.0.3/lib/apksigner.jar sign --ks "/Users/iMac/.local/share/Xamarin/Mono for Android/debug.keystore" --ks-pass pass:android --ks-key-alias androiddebugkey --key-pass pass:android --min-sdk-version 21 --max-sdk-version 28  /Users/iMac/Desktop/Roy/EcomVersioning-master/Ecombeta/Ecombeta.Android/bin/Debug/com.lionmarketing.ecombeta-Signed.apk 
    /Users/iMac/Library/Developer/Xamarin/jdk/microsoft_dist_openjdk_1.8.0.25/bin/java -jar /Users/iMac/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/28.0.3/lib/apksigner.jar sign --ks "/Users/iMac/.local/share/Xamarin/Mono for Android/debug.keystore" --ks-pass pass:android --ks-key-alias androiddebugkey --key-pass pass:android --min-sdk-version 21 --max-sdk-version 28  /Users/iMac/Desktop/Roy/EcomVersioning-master/Ecombeta/Ecombeta.Android/bin/Debug/com.lionmarketing.ecombeta-Signed.apk 
    Signed android package 'bin/Debug/com.lionmarketing.ecombeta-Signed.apk'
    Signed android package 'bin/Debug/com.lionmarketing.ecombeta-Signed.apk'
Target _Upload:
    Detecting installed packages...
Target _Upload:
    Detecting installed packages...

Detecting installed packages


Detecting installed packages
    Copying application to device...
    10% ... 896kb of 8697kb copied
    Copying application to device...
    10% ... 896kb of 8697kb copied


Installing application on device


Installing application on device

    100% ... 8697kb of 8697kb copied
    90% ... 7872kb of 8697kb copied
    100% ... 8697kb of 8697kb copied
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(607,2): error ADB1000:  Deployment failed
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(607,2): error ADB1000: Mono.AndroidTools.RequiresUninstallException: The installed package is incompatible. Please manually uninstall and try again.
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(607,2): error ADB1000:   at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess (System.String output, System.String packageName) [0x00136] in /Users/runner/runners/2.164.1/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Mono.AndroidTools/Internal/AdbOutputParsing.cs:339 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(607,2): error ADB1000:   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice+<>c__DisplayClass95_0.<InstallPackage>b__0 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] t) [0x00016] in /Users/runner/runners/2.164.1/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Mono.AndroidTools/AndroidDevice.cs:753 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(607,2): error ADB1000:   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1[TAntecedentResult].InnerInvoke () [0x00024] in <7d0bc631cadd4a07bf74717847e90cfa>:0 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(607,2): error ADB1000:   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-08/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2319 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(607,2): error ADB1000: --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(607,2): error ADB1000: 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(607,2): error ADB1000:   at AndroidDeviceExtensions.PushAndInstallPackage (Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice device, System.String apkFile, System.String packageName, System.Boolean reinstall, Mono.AndroidTools.Adb.AdbProgressReporter notifyProgress, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x00189] in /Users/runner/runners/2.164.1/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Xamarin.AndroidTools/Devices/AndroidDeviceExtensions.cs:187 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(607,2): error ADB1000:   at AndroidDeviceExtensions.PushAndInstallPackage (Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice device, System.String apkFile, System.String packageName, System.Boolean reinstall, Mono.AndroidTools.Adb.AdbProgressReporter notifyProgress, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x00310] in /Users/runner/runners/2.164.1/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Xamarin.AndroidTools/Devices/AndroidDeviceExtensions.cs:194 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(607,2): error ADB1000:   at AndroidDeviceExtensions.PushAndInstallPackage (Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice device, System.String apkFile, System.String packageName, System.Boolean reinstall, Mono.AndroidTools.Adb.AdbProgressReporter notifyProgress, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x003df] in /Users/runner/runners/2.164.1/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Xamarin.AndroidTools/Devices/AndroidDeviceExtensions.cs:203 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(607,2): error ADB1000:   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.InstallPackage () [0x002ea] in /Users/runner/runners/2.164.1/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Xamarin.AndroidTools/Sessions/AndroidDeploySession.cs:414 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(607,2): error ADB1000:   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.RunAsync (System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x003ae] in /Users/runner/runners/2.164.1/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Xamarin.AndroidTools/Sessions/AndroidDeploySession.cs:217 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(607,2): error ADB1000:   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.RunLoggedAsync (System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x0002f] in /Users/runner/runners/2.164.1/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Xamarin.AndroidTools/Sessions/AndroidDeploySession.cs:119 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(607,2): error ADB0030: Mono.AndroidTools.RequiresUninstallException: The installed package is incompatible. Please manually uninstall and try again.
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(607,2): error ADB0030:   at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess (System.String output, System.String packageName) [0x00136] in /Users/runner/runners/2.164.1/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Mono.AndroidTools/Internal/AdbOutputParsing.cs:339 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(607,2): error ADB0030:   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice+<>c__DisplayClass95_0.<InstallPackage>b__0 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] t) [0x00016] in /Users/runner/runners/2.164.1/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Mono.AndroidTools/AndroidDevice.cs:753 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(607,2): error ADB0030:   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1[TAntecedentResult].InnerInvoke () [0x00024] in <7d0bc631cadd4a07bf74717847e90cfa>:0 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(607,2): error ADB0030:   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-08/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2319 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(607,2): error ADB0030: --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(607,2): error ADB0030: 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(607,2): error ADB0030:   at AndroidDeviceExtensions.PushAndInstallPackage (Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice device, System.String apkFile, System.String packageName, System.Boolean reinstall, Mono.AndroidTools.Adb.AdbProgressReporter notifyProgress, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x00189] in /Users/runner/runners/2.164.1/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Xamarin.AndroidTools/Devices/AndroidDeviceExtensions.cs:187 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(607,2): error ADB0030:   at AndroidDeviceExtensions.PushAndInstallPackage (Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice device, System.String apkFile, System.String packageName, System.Boolean reinstall, Mono.AndroidTools.Adb.AdbProgressReporter notifyProgress, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x00310] in /Users/runner/runners/2.164.1/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Xamarin.AndroidTools/Devices/AndroidDeviceExtensions.cs:194 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(607,2): error ADB0030:   at AndroidDeviceExtensions.PushAndInstallPackage (Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice device, System.String apkFile, System.String packageName, System.Boolean reinstall, Mono.AndroidTools.Adb.AdbProgressReporter notifyProgress, System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x003df] in /Users/runner/runners/2.164.1/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Xamarin.AndroidTools/Devices/AndroidDeviceExtensions.cs:203 
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(607,2): error ADB0030:   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.InstallPackage () [0x002ea] in /Users/runner/runners/2.164.1/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Xamarin.AndroidTools/Sessions/AndroidDeploySession.cs:414 

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(607,2): error ADB0030:   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.RunLoggedAsync (System.Threading.CancellationToken token) [0x0002f] in /Users/runner/runners/2.164.1/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/monodroid/tools/msbuild/external/androidtools/Xamarin.AndroidTools/Sessions/AndroidDeploySession.cs:119 
    2 Warning(s)
    2 Error(s)
```

Comment: The error message states that 'The installed package is incompatible. Please manually uninstall and try again.' Did you tried that? It may depend on a certificate, that was created on your pc first, and now, since you are deploying from a different machine, it does not match anymore.

Comment: Okay I got it to Work Its a bug apparently https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/858509/adb0030-monoandroidtoolsrequiresuninstallexception-2.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a workaround, steps that worked for me :

- uninstall app
- Goto to the manifest file and rename the package name (e.g: com.mycompnay.myapp -> com.mycompnay.myapp2)
- deploy to the real device, that should work
- Uninsnatll the myapp2 from device
- go back to the manifest file and restore the original package name (com.mycompnay.myapp2 -> com.mycompnay.myapp)
- you can debug and deploy

Answer (score 0):

1. Manually uninstall the app using `adb uninstall <package_name>`. More information about this step can be found [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25927723/7395170).
2. Deploy again.