# Flutter - completely uninstall app from emulator

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

Is there any way to completely uninstall an app from the Android emulator?

I want to get rid of the database file that my app uses. I have tried

> flutter clean

but when I go to the Device File Explorer in the emulator, the files are still there in the app folder, and I can see the db file in the databases folder.

I am using Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio : How to uninstall APK (or execute adb command) automatically before Run or Debug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25927124/android-studio-how-to-uninstall-apk-or-execute-adb-command-automatically-bef)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out, I have to run :

```
adb uninstall <package>
```