# Simulate the solution for Security Alert - unsafe implementation of X509TrustManager

Tags: android, android-security, developer-console

So, Lately I am getting the below warning inside my developer console and to resolve the same I have done the required fixes.

[image]

As suggested by Google , [here](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/6346016)

**To confirm you’ve made the correct changes, submit the updated version of your app to the Developer Console and check back after five hours. If the app hasn’t been correctly upgraded, we will display a warning.**

But , if I do the same then whole of my app users will be notified and if the problem is not fixed completely then I will have to do further changes and re-upload the app to the play-store.

I was wondering , if there is any other simulation that can help me to ensure that the issue is completely fixed and then only I move forward for publishing the app.

Comment: that´s disgusting...every time google give you a warning or also blocking your app, they only say there is someting wrong. But in some cases, it will be very helpful to know what exactly is wrong. I mean, it seems that they check the source code in any way, so why do they not say what´s the  problem? :(

Comment: It´s definetely a good question and if you get a solution, you should post it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well , when nothing worked , then I did upload a newer version of my apk to the play-store and later on after a week I guess , the warnings were gone.

But yes you have to resolve the issue in your code and nothing else as far as the simulation concerned is present.