# Android: show package name of installed app

Tags: android, terminal, package-name

Hello i'm using this command line to install an apk on Android :

pm install /sdcard/Download/xxx.apk

i'd like to know the package name of the installed apk , how can i do that ? note : i can't open the manifest , and can't install aapt on my device , i'm looking for a way solely using the pm terminal command ( or other android terminal commands )

Comment: I haven't tried it but have read the [docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html#pm). Maybe you can call `pm install -i my.custom.package.name /path/to/apk`? 

Answer (score -1):

Seems like it was asked before, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289149/read-the-package-name-of-an-android-apk)

```
aapt dump badging path-to-apk | grep package:\ name
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help , please consider reading the question the next time : " and can't install aapt on my device": line 4.

Comment: If you believe a question has been answered before, please flag it as a duplicate rather than duplicating the existing answer in the question. In this case, the question you linked is not a duplicate as the OP specifically states he cannot use aapt