# Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS]

Tags: android, adb

**command**

When I  try to update a new version from  server by downloading apk,
then `enter` install it, but  failed to get installed, so I used adb command to install error found pkg:

```
 /data/local/tmp/ntsj_2018012614.apk *
   Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS]**
```

Comment: do you have the same application already installed in the device? Did you try increasing the version code of app?

Comment: i update  version code   i want to replace  the old version  but  fail

Comment: when  in studio terminal  use  command  adb to  install   error  is

Comment: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS]

Comment: using emulator or device?

Comment: device  emulator  both

Comment: Adb command does not seem to accept the apk with same package name... you can build the apk and drag and drop the apk file directly on emulator... it should work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adb can't install an apk if the device already have an apk installed where the package name is the same. So, you need to remove it by using:

```
adb uninstall com.your.package.name
```

where `com.your.package.name` is your apk package name. Or you can use the following if you want to keep all the apk data (in case you want to update the apk):

```
adb uninstall -k com.your.package.name
```

Then you can install the apk with:

```
adb install yourpackage.apk
```

In case you don't know the package name, please read more about it at [Read the package name of an Android APK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289149/read-the-package-name-of-an-android-apk/37324607)

Comment: i  have  solved  that problem  ,because   targetsdkversion

Comment: @uglyant: Great! can you make it as an answer then accept it so the question is closed?

Comment: owww... I forgot that your question is closed..