# How to run monkeyrunner on an already installed .apk

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

I'm trying to run some commands on an application that is already installed through monkeyrunner. I've edited the sample code listed on d.android.com and I changed it to this:

```
# Imports the monkeyrunner modules used by this program
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice

# Connects to the current device, returning a MonkeyDevice object
device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()

# Installs the Android package. Notice that this method returns a boolean, so you can test
# to see if the installation worked.
device.installPackage('myproject/bin/MyApplication.apk')

# sets a variable with the package's internal name
package = 'com.example.myTestApp'

# sets a variable with the name of an Activity in the package
# activity = 'com.example.android.myapplication.MainActivity'

# sets the name of the component to start
runComponent = package

# Runs the component
device.startActivity(component=runComponent)

# Presses the Menu button
device.press('KEYCODE_MENU', MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP)

# Takes a screenshot
result = device.takeSnapshot()

# Writes the screenshot to a file
result.writeToFile('myproject/shot1.png','png')
```

As you can see, I changed the code to (hopefully) open `com.example.myTestApp` But it doesn't open my application, but it seems it runs the commands on the current application. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

You should specify the Activity in `runComponent` as

```
runComponent = package + "/" + activity
```

To get the names of the launchable Activities:

```
$ aapt dump badging <name>.apk | grep launchable-activity
```

Comment: What if I only know the package and not the activity?

Comment: For example, I can find the package name of another application on my phone by grabbing the package name from the URL in play.google.com.

Comment: May be you can check logcat messages for what is displayed while attempting to open your application.Check for log something like "displayed"..I have seen activity name in case of settings app and some other applications.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to get the launch activity from an any installed apk from the play store using this method:

[get launchable activity name of package from adb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12698814/get-launchable-activity-name-of-package-from-adb)

```
adb shell pm list packages -f
```

Then you can use adb pull:

```
adb pull <APK path from previous command> <toYourDesiredLocation>
```

For Example:(adb pull /system/app/MyAPK.apk C:\someLocation)

and then aapt to get the information you want (aapt is currently located in ~\sdk\build-tools\android-4.3):

```
aapt dump badging <FromYourDesiredLocation\pulledfile.apk>
```

then look for launchable-activity: name='SomeActivityName'

Hope that helps someone else looking for the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

First check whether your app is installed.

```
apk_path = device.shell('pm path com.xx.yy')
if apk_path.startswith('package:'):
    print "XXXYY already installed."
else:
    print "XXXYY app is not installed, installing APKs..."
    device.installPackage('D:/path to apk/yourapp.apk')
```

refer http://antoine-merle.com/introduction-to-the-monkey-runner-tool-2/