# Programmatically control android emulator

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I have a requirement where I need to launch an app on an emulator from a standalone Java application. Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute the following adb command using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("application.exe");`

```
"adb shell am start PACKAGE_NAME/.ACTIVITY_NAME"
```

Note : ACTIVITY_NAME---> Is the name of your Launcher Activity.

Comment: Thanks a lot Don. But the problem is I don't have access to the Activity name as it is not my app. I want to be able to launch any app installed on the emulator. Do you know if this is doable?

Comment: You will get both package name & Launcher Activity name in a tricky way. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12698814/get-launchable-activity-name-of-package-from-adb?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Comment: Ah that's what I  thought. Thanks a lot Don, this was huge help.