# Appium: How to switch in Mobile App from native App to Mobile Web Browser and run URL on Browser in mobile

Tags: selenium, appium, appium-android, appium-ios

I have a native mobile App and automated by using a Appium Driver (AppiumDriver driver) which is working OK and by one Feature of App e.g. unlock Account send an Email to user which need to be confirmed by User.

So I have find out how to get the link in Email and how to get the URL from send Email.(saved in a String var e.g. "href")

So when the automation run I am in Mobile App in window "INFORMATION" which inform user we have send an Email to confirm.
Now my question is

1. How can I switch from native mobile App (screen INFORMATION)and Put the URL in Browser and after that should open in Browser a Window which ask user enter new password and repeat it and then press OK ?
   After that I should again back to the Mobile App.
2. Do I need another driver like a Web Driver (additional to appium Driver mentioned above) to handle the Actions in Browser after switch?

Thanks for any Support

This my Capability:

```
public AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver;
```

.....

```
public DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
```

.....

```
            cap.setCapability("deviceName", helper.getConfiguration(configFileName, "androidDeviceName"));
            cap.setCapability("platformName", helper.getConfiguration(configFileName, "androidPlatformName"));
            cap.setCapability("PlatformVersion", helper.getConfiguration(configFileName, "androidPlatformVersion"));
            cap.setCapability("automationName", "uiautomator2");

            cap.setCapability("MobileCapabilityType.FULL_RESET", android_mct_fullReset);
            cap.setCapability("MobileCapabilityType.NO_RESET", android_mct_noReset);
            cap.setCapability("appium-version", helper.getConfiguration(configFileName, "appiumVersion"));
            cap.setCapability("language", helper.deviceLanguage);
            cap.setCapability("locale", helper.deviceLocale);
            cap.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.UNICODE_KEYBOARD, "true");
            cap.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
```

....

```
        driver = new AppiumDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"), cap);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this will be achieved with :

```
driver.startActivity(new Activity("com.example", "ActivityName"));
```

Import by :

```
import io.appium.java_client.android.Activity;
```

With this method you can switch application, you must know the `APP_PACKAGE` and `APP_ACTIVITY` that you have, try [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12698814/get-launchable-activity-name-of-package-from-adb) or [this link](http://www.automationtestinghub.com/apppackage-and-appactivity-name/) to learn this.

This is example the `APP_PACKAGE` and `APP_ACTIVITY` `google chrome browser` from play store :

```
driver.startActivity(new Activity("com.android.chrome", "com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main"));
```

You don't need to make a new initialize driver for the `browser`, just do it.

```
Your native apps start here
...

Switch to browser

//example chrome
driver.startActivity(new Activity("com.android.chrome", "com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main"));
....

//back to last activity your native app
driver.startActivity(new Activity("yourAPP_PACKAGE", "yourAPP_ACTIVITY"));
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use [Activity](https://static.javadoc.io/io.appium/java-client/7.1.0/io/appium/java_client/android/Activity.html) class to launch another application using [AndroidDriver.startActivity()](https://static.javadoc.io/io.appium/java-client/7.1.0/io/appium/java_client/android/StartsActivity.html#startActivity-io.appium.java_client.android.Activity-) function like:

   ```
   Activity activity = new Activity("activity.package", "activity.name");
   activity.setStopApp(false);
   ((AndroidDriver<MobileElement>) driver).startActivity(activity);
   ```
2. An easier way would be just going for [Launch](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Launch) command available via [SeeTest Appium Extension](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/SeeTest+-+Appium+Extension) like:

   ```
   seetest.launch("activity.name", false, false);
   ```