# Get Info About an Android App

Tags: android

Is there a way to get info on an Android application (e.g., publisher name) if you know the name of the package?  I don't see it in packageinfo or applicationinfo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is not in `PackageInfo` or `ApplicationInfo`, then it is not accessible via `PackageManager`. For example, "publisher name" is only something that a marketplace like the Play Store knows -- that is not a piece of metadata that a developer needs to put into the APK.

Comment: Yeah, I was looking for a way to query the Play store to get the info that I needed.

Answer (score 1):

`Is there a way to get info on an Android application (e.g., publisher name) if you know the name of the package?`

Checkout

1) [get application name from package name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841161/get-application-name-from-package-name)

2) [Find package name for Android apps to use Intent to launch Market app from web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789462/find-package-name-for-android-apps-to-use-intent-to-launch-market-app-from-web) questions.

You may get some details using [PackageManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) and [ApplicationInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html). The first one seems to answer that. Hope this is of some use to you.

Comment: I tried PackageInfo, which contains ApplicationInfo, and that doesn't have what I need

Comment: @CommonsWare has already answered your question. In CommonsWare we trust.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst the original question turned out to be about how to get the Play Store information for an application, there is often information to be discovered about the app publisher or developer (not always the same thing) by looking at the apk on the device.

For example, the package name is in a reversed domain name form, such as com.google.android.apps.maps, and thus gives you a pretty big clue that this is a Google published application.

Apks also contain certificate(s) which are available via packageInfo.signatures.  These signatures are "unregulated" (they are generally self signed) and thus can contain anything so should not be trusted to be truthful, but in practice often give a good indication as to the developer (even to the extent of many of them containing the personal name of the lead programmer of the app!)

You can use an app such as [App Detective](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zmarties.detective) to see the signatures contained in your device's installed apps.